# C++11 type of variable in expression?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 I'm somewhat confused about the difference between the types `T` and `reference to T` as they apply to expressions that name variables.  Specifically consider:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    int& y = x;

    x; // (1)
    y; // (2)
}
```

What is the type of the expression `x` in (1) in the above?  Is it `int` or `lvalue reference to int` ?  (Its value category is clearly an `lvalue`, but this is separate from its type)

Likewise what is the type of the expression `y` at (2) in the above?  Is it `int` or `lvalue reference to int` ?

It says in 5.1.1.8:

> The type of [an identifier primary expression] is the type of the identiﬁer.
>   The result is the entity denoted by the identiﬁer. The result is an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable, or data member and a prvalue otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bit you're missing is this (§5/5):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

So although the identifier `y` has type `int&`, the expression `y` has type `int`. An expression never has reference type, so the type of both of your expressions is `int`.

Comment: As I like to think of it, "values never have reference type, only variables do".

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes values have value categories instead I guess.

Comment: @KerrekSB: A different approach that I find more sensible is that reference is just an alias to the original object. After the reference is created any use of the reference and the original object are exactly equivalent

Answer (score 3):

The expression denotes an *lvalue* of type `int`, in both cases. An expression cannot be a *reference*, although you can *bind* the result of an expression with an *lvalue* or *rvalue* reference.